# Уведомления на экране блокировки Android

Tags: java, android, уведомления

Доброго всем времени суток!

Я столкнулся с проблемой, что нужно вывести уведомление на экран блокировки. Начиная с версии Андроида 5.0 все работает отлично благодаря `.setVisibility()`, но хочется сделать поддержку вывода уведомления на экран блокировки и на более ранних версия ( SDK < 21 ), а так же, чтобы можно было реагировать на нажатие кнопки на уведомлении.

Уведомление у меня запускается из Сервиса.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для отображения оповещения на экране блокировки необходимо установить приоритет выше, чем стандартный - 1 или 2. Например,

Приоритет действует как подсказка пользовательскому интерфейсу устройства о том, каким образом следует выводить уведомление. Чтобы задать приоритет уведомления, вызовите метод `NotificationCompat.Builder.setPriority()` и передайте ему одну из констант приоритетов NotificationCompat. Имеется пять уровней приоритета, начиная от PRIORITY_MIN (-2) и до PRIORITY_MAX (2). Если приоритет не задан, то по умолчанию он будет иметь значение PRIORITY_DEFAULT (0).

Также, для работы с кнопками в уведомлении, необходимо использовать расширенный макет.
Подробнее тут https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Comment: Это от приоритета не зависит, если установлена защита (графический ключ, код...), то уведомление будет показано, но содержимое его будет скрыто.

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение проблемы - [RemoteControlClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RemoteControlClient.html).

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.